# problem with adding image

Tags: floats

I am trying to add a figure to my `.pdf` document using TeXstudio but it doesn't fit on the page.

I tried to add scale, width vs. commands in the brackets after `\includegraphics` but it didn't work. The image is not a screenshot. The code is below. Can you help me guys for this issue?

```
\begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[]{mirrored.jpg}    
        \caption{blaa blaa}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code complete with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but it allows us to understand better your problem. I've posted an answer but I don't know if it is exactly what you need. See [this link](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to know how to built a minimal working example (MWE).

Comment: You seem to have a very big picture to insert, so the `[H]` option is likely to produce very bad pagination. Use `[htp]` instead, even if you follow the (correct) advice to resize the picture.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 1):

Try with `graphicx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{mirrored}    
    \caption{blaa blaa}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: `keepaspectratio` is the default when only specifying `width`, so you don't need that.